# Queue Baking Multiple Materials with Multiple UVs into Multiple Textures with the Same UV

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, add-on, baking

can anyone recommend how I can bake:

- A model with multiple UV sets
- That has one texture reapplied across the whole mesh by each of those UVs
- Baked down to a single UV, but a unique output texture each

At the moment I am manually swapping the each UV, grabbing the corresponding texture and then baking, which is a bit slow and dull. So I would like to be able to bake it all at once.
I tried stacking materials, but everything below the first material slot came out black.
I thought about "SimpleBake", but it seems to want to bake everything down to one texture

Are there any bake queueing plugins that allow you to swap the active material on an object and pick a target output texture?

Is it worth animating the values and just treating each frame like a new texture?

Are there any alternative workflows that are actually much simpler that I've overlooked?